# Why do Transformers in Natural Language Processing need a stack of encoders?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, transformer-model

I am following this blog on transformers

http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/

The only thing I don't understand is why there needs to be a stack of encoders or decoders. I understand that the multi-headed attention layers capture different representation spaces of the problem. I don't understand why there needs to be a vertical stack of encoders and decoders. Wouldn't one encoder/decoder layer work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stacking layer is what makes any deep learning architecture powerful, using a single encoder/decoder with attention wouldn't be able to capture the complexity needed to model an entire language or archive high accuracy on tasks as complex as language translation, the use of stacks of encoder/decoders allows the network to extract hierarchical features and model complex problems.

Comment: Is it like the layers in CNN, where low-level features are detected in beginning layers and then high-level features are detected in high level layers?

Comment: Justifying depth doesn't really justify the need for 2 distincts stacks of encoder/decoder, which was the point of the question imo

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR**: Multiple encoders are stacked to capture more complex dependencies in the input sequence. You can think of stacking multiple encoders in a transformer network as analogous to increasing the depth of a CNN.

**Subtle point**: a single encoder can only determine **pairwise** attention on the input tokens.

Consider a transformer with a single encoder. The output of the first encoder layer, which learned pairwise attention between the input tokens, is used as input to the second transformer encoder layer. The second layer then computes another round of self-attention for each token, but this time the attention mechanism can attend to all the tokens in the input sequence **simultaneously** (because the first layer's output already contains information about pairwise attention), allowing for more complex dependencies and interactions to be captured.

As you stack additional encoder layers, the amount of complexity the network can model grows.

Check [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/gpt-3-transformers-and-the-wild-world-of-nlp-9993d8bb1314) for a great slide showing Encoder-only, Decoder-only, and Encoder-Decoder architectures by-name about 3/4 down the page.